# How to solve an ODE with arbitrary constants

Tags: python, python-3.x, differential-equations

I am trying to solve the following ODE using the code below:

```
from scipy.integrate import odeint
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import math


def model(V,t):
    dVdt=a*V-b*V*math.log(V)
    return dVdt
V0=1
a=1
b=1
t = np.linspace(0,20,50)

V=odeint(model,V0,t)

plt.plot(t,V)
plt.xlabel('time')
plt.ylabel('V(t)')
plt.show

plt.plot
```

I want to try and solve this ODE now for arbitrary V0, a, and b. Is there any way I can do this?

Comment: By arbitrary V0, a & b do you mean integrate symbolically rather than numerically? If so look into sympy.

Comment: You can solve this by hand, it is easy to see that `d/dt log(a-b*log(V))=-b` so that `a-b*log(V)=(a-b*log(V0))*exp(-b*t)` etc. Do you have an equation in mind where such a symbolic solution is not (that easy or at all) achievable?